# Get cleos without building EOS?

Tags: cleos

I cloned the EOS repository from github and am trying to get `cleos` installed based on the [wiki](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Local-Environment).

When I get to the step for `./eosio_build.sh` I don't have enough space because of my small SSD:

> ARCHITECTURE Linux
>
> OS name: Ubuntu     OS Version: 16.04   CPU speed: 1099 MHz: MHz:Mhz    CPU
>   cores: 4  Physical Memory: 15929 Mgb  Disk space total: 204G  Disk
>   space available: 75G You must have at least 100GB of available storage
>   to install EOSIO. exiting now

What is the easiest way to setup `cleos` if I don't need to run a node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OSX

```
brew tap eosio/eosio
brew install eosio
```

On Ubuntu 18.04

```
wget https://github.com/eosio/eos/releases/download/v2.0.6/eosio_2.0.6-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./eosio_2.0.6-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb
```

On Ubuntu 16.04

```
wget https://github.com/eosio/eos/releases/download/v2.0.6/eosio_2.0.6-1-ubuntu-16.04_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./eosio_2.0.6-1-ubuntu-16.04_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of compiling EOS yourself you could download a prebuilt Docker container, here are some instructions for how to do that with EOS:

https://www.eosdocs.io/dappdevelopment/software/docker/

I'd recommend doing a basic Docker tutorial first though to understand the basics of that if you're not familiar with it yet.

Comment: that's super cool!

Answer (score 0):

One very workable alternative to using cleos at all is the eosc tool, at https://github.com/eoscanada/eosc

It is implemented in Go and is not dependent on the EOSIO toolchain.